# How to tell if its 1-way, 2-way or 3-way ANOVA?

Tags: anova

The question is:

> A company is testing 3 heating systems installed in 3 identical warehouses of a new factory. The systems were tested for 5 days and the increase in temperature after 3 hourse was recoded. Create an ANOVA table for the data given.

I thought because we were testing 3 heating systems, we would use 3 way anova, but in the answers it says its 1 way.

Is it 1 way because we are just testing heating systems. If we were testing heating and insulation (for example), then it would be 2 way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1-way ANOVA: 1 factor. (1-way ANOVA with a factor with just two levels turns into a t-test.)

2-way ANOVA: 2 factors.

And so on...

The number of levels of each factor has nothing to do with the number of ways.

Comment: what do you mean by "levels"

Comment: The number of possible values a factor variable can take. If you are looking at three heating systems A, B and C, the factor variable "heating system" has three levels A, B and C. Given that you seem to be taking a statistics course, your instructor should have covered this, so I suggest you look into your course notes (or it may be a case of a different language than English).

Comment: No, its more of a case of me being lazy. Thanks for the help though